# looping query from array result

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, select

I have query in MODEL, select data from table1 that contain data as:

```
Column NOPE
```

data1
data2
data3

Then i want to select all data from the result of table1, but only get the first row :

NOPE  | Total
nope1  |  20pax

How to looping all row to select and display all in my VIEW? so i get all row from select like this:
NOPE  TOTAL 
nope1    20pax
nope2    30pax
nope3    25pax
nope4    40pax

This is my model:

```
function test()
{
$query = $this->db->query("select nope from tb1");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {

        $nopen=$row['nope'];
        $query2=$this->dbmssql->query("
                                        select nope, 
                                        count(name) as total 
                                        from trans 
                                        where nope ='$nopen' 
                                        and date='2016-04-20'
                                        group by nope ");
        return $query2->result_array();

    }

}       

}
```

and my VIEW is:

```
                    <tbody> 
                <?php 
                $no=0;
                foreach ($res as $row) { $no++?>                    
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nope'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['total'];?> PAX</td>
                </tr>       
                <?php 
                } ?>    
                </tbody>
```

Please help me, Many Thanks.

Comment: Is there problem in your query or u r just  unable to return the data from the test()

Answer (score 0):

You only get the first row because your foreach loop is executed only once, since the loop exit at the return statement. You need to assign the result array to a variable and return that variable after the loop.

Here is your code modified to execute the foreach loop on every records in $query.

```
function test()
{
   $query = $this->db->query("select nope from tb1");

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
      {

        $nopen=$row['nope'];
        $query2=$this->dbmssql->query("
                                    select nope, 
                                    count(name) as total 
                                    from trans 
                                    where nope ='$nopen' 
                                    and date='2016-04-20'
                                    group by nope ");
          $all_records[]=$query2->result_array();

       }
       return $all_records;
  }       

}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much , can u give me an example to do that?

Comment: thank you salain, i have change the code but get error : <br /> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: nopen

Filename: test/index.php

Line Number: 87 <br /> is there problem with my view code?? maybe i need to change also?

Comment: You have to give more detail on the code on tha line!! Because from the error you specify in your comment, it means you are using "nopen" as an index key for an array.

Comment: Thanks so much Salain, I was change my code follow your code, and make change in my View to call array[], now i get the result... you are my Hero..

Answer (score 0):

Millions thanks for you, Mr.Salain....

finally, i have follow your code, and make changes my VIEW with :

```
                    <?php 
                $no=0;

                foreach ($res as $row) 
                { 
                $no++;
                ?>                  
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0]['nope'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0]['total'];?> PAX</td>
                </tr>       
                <?php

                } ?>
```

and now i get the result all record,..you are my hero...